# lea syntax in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

I understand the LEA means Load Effective Address and have read the documentation.

When I disassemble code using gdb I see:

```
lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
```

I am having trouble understanding what is meant by?

```
0x4(%esp)
```

Does it mean 0x4 offset from %esp or move the contents of ecx into four words above esp?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have read the documentation you know `lea` does not access memory. Also at&t uses `src, dst` order so the contents of `ecx` are definitely not moved anywhere since that is the destinaton. It just does `ecx = esp + 4`. You can switch gnu tools into intel syntax mode if you are confused. Also you can use the debugger to see what is happening.

Comment: Thank you, @Jester, I have always been defeated with Assembly. So in 0x4(%esp) just means add 4 to esp?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it means.